# SE user knows the answer

Tags: riddle

It would be too easy for a long-time SE user familiar with SE network and not too easy for a recently registered one.

The riddle is:

> There you can't find waffles and polyglot anymore, since they are gone to be replaced with simple text and alien ship.

What is this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the

> [Stack Overflow 404 page](https://stackoverflow.com/404)

which used to have

> this code polyglot (A program that works in multiple programming languages) [image]

and before that

> it had this picture of a keyboard waffle maker. [image]

Now it has

> simpler text and a picture of a spaceship [image]

Comment: Oh, I see that the answer is correct, but the hint about simple text has been misinterpreted, although it doesn't really matter :)

Comment: What was the "simple text" hint supposed to mean?

Comment: the fact that, to be precise, waffles is not the Stack Overflow 404 page, but old Meta Stack Overflow 404 page, which is now called [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com). And new [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) serves a different purpose. And Meta Stack Exchange has a simple text 404 - http://meta.stackexchange.com/404.

Comment: So, it's a bit difficult explanation unless you know all the history :)